# Почему код не работает в IE?

Tags: html, javascript, dom

Почему код работает везде, кроме IE? Как сделать кроссбраузерным? В IE таблица не создаётся

```
var tbl = document.createElement("table");
tbl.id = "xotbl2";
var id = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var u = 1; u <= 3; u++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.className = "td";
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = srcn;
        img.id = "ci" + id;
        img.className = "ci";
        img.setAttribute("onclick", "onmouseclick('ci" + id + "');");
        img.setAttribute("onmouseover", "onmouseimgoverorout('cit" + id + "','ci" + id + "','mouseover');");
        img.setAttribute("onmouseout", "onmouseimgoverorout('cit" + id + "','ci" + id + "','mouseout');");
        img.setAttribute("onmousedown", "");
        id++;
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Comment: А что не работает? События не происходят или таблица не отображается как надо?

Comment: Вообще в IE таблица не создаётся!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tbody не сделали.. помнится мне были у IE какие-то возражения на этот счёт.

Comment: Спасибо сработало!

Answer (score 0):

Просто надо заменить

```
img.setAttribute("onmouseover", "onmouseimgoverorout('cit" + id + "','ci" + id + "','mouseover');");
```

на

```
newonmouseover(img,'cit" + id + "','ci" + id + "','mouseover');");
```

и дописать процедуру под тип

```
function newonmouseover(elem,data1,data2,data3){
    elem.onmouseover = function() {
        onmouseimgoverorout(data1,data2,data3);
    }
}
```

Выглядит глупо, но  работает… 
Проверял на IE 6.

Comment: И еще IE не даст Вам создать таблицу с помощью createElement…
Надо воспользоваться var tr = table.insertRow(0); и var td = tr.insertCell(0);

Comment: И еще IE не даст Вам создать таблицу с помощью createElement…
Надо воспользоваться var tr = table.insertRow(0); и var td = tr.insertCell(0);

Answer (score 0):

Ну, знаете, в IE очень много чего не работает так, как в нормальных браузерах. В этом и заключается основная проблема разработки кроссбраузерных приложений.

По этому поводу советую почитать [статью](http://webarticles.neomoon.ru/content/view/22/41/) о кроссбраузерной верстке.

Comment: Может, правильнее было бы оставить комментарий, а не ответ, а?